# programatically change textbox type from type='text' to type='password'

Tags: javascript, validation

i have username and password textboxes. i want them to both show the default text, ie "username" and "password", but when the user clicks on the password box it should dynamically change to a "password" type for security reasons.

i've managed to do this easily enough with javascript code but it doesn't want to work in IE.

```
<input id="username" class="username" name="u" type="text" value="username" onclick="if(this.value='username') {this.value=''};" />
<input id="password" class="password" name="p" type="text" value="password" onclick="if(this.value='password') {this.value=''; this.type='password'};" />
```

Comment: Can, you post your sample codes?

Comment: Assuming you get it working (from one of the answers below), you should also change the trigger from `onclick` to `onfocus`, to allow for when the user tabs between fields rather than using the mouse.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition read "==" (instead of "=")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let say your  html code is    like this

```
<input type="text" id="txtId" />
```

you can replace it by using Jquery,

```
$('#txtId').replaceWith('<input type="password" id="txtId" />')
```

Answer (score 3):

IE only lets you set the type of an `input` element once, when the element is created.  Attempts to set it after that will fail.

If you want to "change" the element in IE, what you'll likely need to do is create another element with the same attributes (except for the type, of course), and replace the existing element with it.

Or create a dummy textbox for the password, and have the real password box hidden -- on focus the dummy box should hide itself, and show and focus on the real password box.

Comment: It's not just IE anymore. Changing the input type is really a huge security risk.  The other browser manufacturers have recognized this.

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider using JQuery?

```
$("[name=fieldname]").attr("type", "password");
```

Comment: yes i'd be happy to user jquery but the issue i'm having is that it will change the field type in everything but IE

Comment: (1) "Use jQuery" is not always the answer.  (2) This is an IE-specific issue.  IE won't let you change the "type" attribute once it's set.

Comment: Uh.. You could try replace the field all together with a password field when it's clicked? Also - though "Use JQuery" is not always the answer, it is frequently the solution; a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to replace any form element by a password with the same value, knowing its id:

```
function replaceWithPassword(id)
{
    var o = $('input#' + id + ', textarea#'+id + ', select#'+id);
    o.replaceWith('<input type="password" value="' + o.val() + '" id="' + id + '" />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
Put this in the head section

```
function changeBack()
 {
     if(document.getElementById('smsl_pw').value=='')
     {
        document.getElementById('smsl_pw').type='text';
        document.getElementById('smsl_pw').value='Password';

     }

 }

 function changePass()
 {
    document.getElementById('smsl_pw').type='password'; 
    document.getElementById('smsl_pw').value='';

 }
```

Here is the input field
`<input id="smsl_pw" onclick="changePass();" onblur="changeBack();" name="smsl_pw" type="text" value="Password">`

Hope it helps someone