# Dynamically assigning attributes to input fields in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have recently developed a javascript class used to assign attributes to input fields. The class works flawlessly in Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari but gives error in Internet Explorer. (Command not supported.)

I have tred both with:

```
this.my_element.type = "xxx";
```

As well as with:

```
this.my_element.setAttribute("type", xxx);
```

Both returning the same error. Is there any alternative way I could handle input fields in IE, possibly without having to write separate codes for IE/Other Browsers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure IE doesn't allow you to change the "type" attribute of an input element, with the one exception being to assign it an initial value after creating an element dynamically. You can work around this by replacing the entire element with another of the new type - I know it's clunky, but that's IE for you. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5878636/615754) for more info. You should have no problem changing other attributes, e.g., id, name, value, class.

Comment: I am first using a class to dynamically create a general input field: `<input />` and then using a further class to assign type, name, class, id etc... I am not trying to _replace_ the type attribute, rather, to add one _ex novo_.

Comment: I don't think there is a "general input field" is there? By default type will be "text" if not specified. Please show some code for how you create the element and how you add it to the page. If you are creating the input using something like `newInput = document.createElement("input")` then in IE you will need to set the type as the next step *before* you actually add it to the page (I assume you proceed to add it to the page using `someExistingElement.appendChild(newInput)` or insertBefore() or something.)

Answer (score 1):

You can only set the `type` of an `<input>` element before it's been inserted into the document in IE. Once it's in the document, it's too late.

Example:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "button";
input.name = "foo";
input.value = "bar";
document.body.appendChild(input);
```